# WPF ComboBox SelectedValue binding with null value shows up blank

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, datatemplate

I have a problem while trying to bind 2 or more Comboboxes SelectedValue to a property, that is null. 
Only 1 of the comboboxes bound to this property will show the real value.

Below is my Xaml where i use DataTemplate to select a Combobox for presentation of the viewModel.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PropertyValueViewModel}">
        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Value}" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableValues}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="These uses template:"></Label>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ValueSelector}"></ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ValueSelector}"></ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ValueSelector}"></ContentPresenter>
</StackPanel>
```

And the code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ValueSelector = new PropertyValueViewModel()
        {
            SelectableValues = new List<SelectableValue>()
            {
                new SelectableValue("NULL", null),
                new SelectableValue("1", 1)
            },
            Value = null
        };

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueSelectorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ValueSelector", typeof(PropertyValueViewModel), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(PropertyValueViewModel)));

    public PropertyValueViewModel ValueSelector
    {
        get { return (PropertyValueViewModel)GetValue(ValueSelectorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueSelectorProperty, value); }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// My viewModel
/// </summary>
public class PropertyValueViewModel
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public object SelectableValues { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// The items in the combobox
/// </summary>
public class SelectableValue
{
    public SelectableValue(string header, object value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Description = header;
    }

    public object Value { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now i am wondering why only 1 of them can show the NULL value at startup?
I can change the value in any of them, and they will all sync with the value in the property - if i select 1 and then back to NULL, they will all show NULL.
It seems like its only the initial value is not shown correctly.

If i avoid using DataTemplate the binding works too.
Does anyone know why the DAtaTemplate behaves this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting problem.

Fundamentally, this appears to be caused by your choice to use `null` as one of the selectable values. `null`, of course, has special meaning, for C#, .NET, and WPF. The problem also involves the order in which the initialization of the `ComboBox` element is done. The `SelectedValuePath` property is initialized *after* the `SelectedValue` property.

This means that as your program is starting up and the `ComboBox` elements are created, when `null` is assigned to the `SelectedValue` property through its binding, the `ComboBox` does not yet have enough information to handle that value as a legitimate item selection. Instead, it interprets it as no selection at all.

Why does the *last* `ComboBox` still get initialized the way you want? I'm not really sure…I didn't investigate very far regarding that. I could speculate, but the odds of my guessing correctly seem low so I won't bother. Since it's the anomaly and not necessarily in keeping with expected behavior (based on above, even if the behavior is the *desired* behavior) I'll chalk it up to one of WPF's many "quirks". :)

I found several work-arounds for the issue:

- Don't use `null` as a selectable value. If every selectable value is non-null, then the non-null value used to initialize each element's `SelectedValue` property is retained and when the `SelectedValuePath` is initialized, the current selection for the `ComboBox` is set correctly.
- Don't use `SelectedValuePath`. Instead, just bind to `SelectedItem` and initialize the `Value` property with the desired `SelectableValue` class instance (e.g. the first one in the list).
- In the `ComboBox`'s `Loaded` event, refresh the target of the binding.

The first two are significant departures from your current design. Personally, if at all possible I would go with one or the other. It seems to me that there's a clear danger in using `null` as a selectable value in a `ComboBox`, and this may not be the only oddity you run into. In the long run, maintenance of this part of the code may cost a lot more if you continue to use `null`.

That said, the third option does work, and if you're lucky, the only real hazard in using `null` is on initialization. My proposed work-around for that option would look something like this:

**XAML:**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PropertyValueViewModel}">
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Value}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableValues}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Description"
              SelectedValuePath="Value"
              Loaded="comboBox_Loaded"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**C#:**

```
private void comboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)e.OriginalSource;

    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(comboBox, ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty)
                     .UpdateTarget();
}
```

This forces WPF to update the target (i.e. the `SelectedValue` property of the control). Since at this point, the `SelectedValuePath` has been set, assigning `null` to the property this time correctly updates the selected item for the `ComboBox`.

By the way, I would strongly recommend that you disambiguate the names of the `Value` properties in your models. Having two different `Value` properties used for bindings in a single XAML element is very confusing. I would use, for example, `SelectedValue` and `ItemValue`, for the `PropertyValueViewModel` class and the `SelectableValue` class, respectively.